# Exclude DataSource inside starter library from auto configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have multiple Spring Boot Starters, each of which define a DataSource like this:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.unique.namespace.datasource")
public DataSource someUniqueNamespaceDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public SomeOtherBean someOtherBean() {
  return new SomeOtherBean(someUniqueNamespaceDataSource())
}
```

As you can see, the bean method `someUniqueNamespaceDataSource()` is being called directly in another bean method, within the same configuration class. However, Spring Boot is intercepting the method, and then performing its own internal injection. This time, it injects with a type of DataSource.

When an application uses one of these starters, it works without issue. However, when it uses multiple starters, I get errors like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: someUniqueNamespaceDataSource,someOtherUniqueNamespaceDataSource
```

I believe this is because Spring Boot is internally injected by type, even though my code injects a qualified bean.

Is there some way that the starter libraries can indicate that the DataSources should not be considered candidates for auto-configuration?

Is there some way that an application depending on more than one of these starter libraries can exclude them from auto-configuration?

Disabling auto-configuration entirely is not really viable. Additionally, manually excluding all current auto-configurations that trigger on existence of a DataSource bean is far too brittle because the addition of dependencies later, especially transitive dependencies, which trigger based on a DataSource bean, will reintroduce the error.

Comment: But how are you autowiring the data sources?

Answer (score 0):

In your `@SpringBootApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations set `exclude` property to:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the approach I am forced to take at the moment. However, I think it is far too brittle.

For example, I am not yet using JPA/Hibernate so excluding HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration is both unnecessary and looks odd. However, if I do use it, or any other starter that is conditional on DataSource, in the future, then the error will reoccur.